# How to encode a file via the key vault rest api (Content of 'value' is not base64url.) in bash

Tags: azure-keyvault

I am trying to use the [Key Vault encrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/encrypt/encrypt#jsonwebkeyencryptionalgorithm) REST API using a Bash script. I'm unable to convert a file to a base64url which the API seems to require.

My call looks like this and it works if I use a simple, short string, but not when sending file content:

```
curl -vv -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"alg\":\"RSA-OAEP-256\",\"value\":\"$value\"}" "https://***.vault.azure.net/keys/***/***/encrypt?api-version=7.2"
```

Attempt 1:

```
value=$(base64 test-input.txt)
Result: Content of 'value' is not base64url. Property 'value' is required.
```

Attempt 2

```
value=$(base64 -w 0 test-input.txt)
Result: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Attempt 3

```
value=$(base64 test-input.txt | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '=')
Result: Content of 'value' is not base64url. Property 'value' is required.
```

Attempt 4

```
value=$(base64 test-input.txt -w 0 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '=')
Result: The parameter is incorrect.
```

What is the proper way to format the content so that Key Vault accepts it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper Base64Url encoder. You should test the output of your function to ensure that it works as expected.

It's not clear which language you're using to achieve this or I would point you to a proper method call.

Comment: I mentioned in the title that I'm trying to do this in bash. Guess I have to switch to a framework then, if plain bash doesn't work. The output of the function can be inspected with `echo $value`. But I don't know what Azure expects, so it doesn't help me.

Comment: Your title didn’t make it clear at all.  However, I see you’re trying to do the conversion.  I think you need to test your converted text to a known-good base64url converter in order to determine why it’s not working.

Comment: I've updated the first paragraph to also mention Bash, so that's more clear. Yes, I could try to use another framework, but I was hoping someone had done this before in Bash. If `base64` is not a good library, I was hoping someone could recommend a better library. I don't see how getting this to work in say Node.JS or Java helps me with Bash though...

Comment: My point is that you are likely converting incorrectly.  You should tweak your conversion scheme until it works properly by comparing it next to a known good output.

Comment: But this is exactly my question. I've tried several ways, as can be seen my attempts. None were successful so I wrote this question...

Comment: Please provide a sample of some base64url encoded text that does not work in this instance for review.